# How can I bridge AspNetCore SignalR 1.0.0 alpha2 and SignalR 2.2.2

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm experimenting with ASP.NET Core (targeting the 4.6.1 framework) with SignalR 1.0.0-alpha2-final and Angular 5 to try to rewrite our application using SPA technologies.

I have several calculation services written with the .NET 4.6.1 framework, and I have no choice but to use SignalR 2.2.2 to host a hub.

Because the ASP.NET Core SignalR Client is not compatible with SignalR 2.2.2 hubs, I would like to write a bridge between the two, in the form of a service in the ASP.NET Core middleware. .

The principle is as follows:

- My calculation services host a SignalR 2.2.2 hub send messages to the middleware, which uses the SignalR 2.2.2 client
- The middleware is both a SignalR 2.2.2 client and a host of a SignalR 1.0.0-alpha2-final hub to receive signals from the calculation services and send them to the client using SignalR with Angular.

---

```
private readonly IHubContext<HubForSignalR100> _hub;

public BridgeService(IHubContext<HubForSignalR100> hubContext) {
    // hub contexts for the SignalR 1.0.0 clients
    _hub = hubContext;

    // Hub connection to the service that host signalr 2.2.2
    var cn = new HubConnection(urlToTheCalcService);
    var hub = cn.CreateHubProxy("CalculationServiceHub");

    // When the calculation service send a signalr 2.2.2 event, it is resent to the signalr 1.0.0 clients
    hub.On<CalculationData>("CalculationEvent", async data => {
        await _hub.Clients.All.InvokeAsync("CalculationEvent", data);
    });
    cli.Start().Wait();
}
```

Because I have a lot of calculation services and I dont want to map every messages, I would like to make it more transparent, something like

```
    hub.On(async (eventName, data) => {
        await _hub.Clients.All.InvokeAsync(eventName, data);
    });
```

Unfortunately I am unable to find anything in SignalR apis that looks close to this approach. How can I bridge ASP.NET core SignalR with SignalR 2.2.2 a transparent way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... There is probably no way to perform this at this stage.
So I kept SignalR for the push notifications, and I ended up using MassTransit and RabbitMQ to between my MiddleWare and my Calculation Services.